# How to access gradient editor in Unity3D?

Tags: colors, background, unity-game-engine

I was searching through the Unity manual to see what they had for gradient effects and I found this:

[image]

Here is the link:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/EditingValueProperties.html

However, I can't find this editor anywhere inside of Unity. I want to use this to apply a gradient to my background for a game. Does it exist!?

Comment: I've only seen the Gradient Editor window when managing colors in the Particle System component, when editing "Color over Lifetime" and "Color by Speed". Googling *unity3d create gradient* seems to suggest you can create gradients by code, otherwise maybe try importing your own texture.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. Try gamedev.stackexchange.com or Unity Answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have access to arbitrarily use color picker or gradient editor. For your purpose of making the background you have several options,

1. Change the [Camera background color](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Camera.html) from the editor.
2. Use a [Skybox](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/graphics/using-skyboxes), you can [make your own skybox](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UseSkybox.html) too.
3. If your game has a limited view, use a plane with a [custom material](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Material.html).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this script shows how you can use Gradients. You need to add this script to one of your `GameObject` in your scene. And your `Camera`'s tag is `MainCamera` .

This code based on [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gradient.html).

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class GradientHandler : MonoBehaviour {

    public Camera camera;
    public Gradient gradient;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        camera = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<Camera>() as Camera; //Gets Camera script from MainCamera object(Object's tag is MainCamera).
        GradientColorKey[] colorKey = new GradientColorKey[2];
        GradientAlphaKey[] alphaKey = new GradientAlphaKey[2];
        // Populate the color keys at the relative time 0 and 1 (0 and 100%)
        colorKey[0].color = Color.red;
        colorKey[0].time = 0.0f;
        colorKey[1].color = Color.blue;
        colorKey[1].time = 1.0f;
        // Populate the alpha  keys at relative time 0 and 1  (0 and 100%)
        alphaKey[0].alpha = 1.0f;
        alphaKey[0].time = 0.0f;
        alphaKey[1].alpha = 0.0f;
        alphaKey[1].time = 1.0f;
        gradient.SetKeys(colorKey, alphaKey);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        Debug.Log ("Time: "+Time.deltaTime);
        camera.backgroundColor = gradient.Evaluate(Time.time%1);
    }
}
```